# Calling a .EXE from Websphere-MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

This a follow-up based on [MQ (Websphere 7) persist message to file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293522/mq-websphere-7-persist-message-to-file-system).

How do you set up an .exe program from an MQ support pack (such as the Q utility in MA01) to execute each time a message is received?  Can this be setup in MQ Explorer?  (We are using 7.0 on Windows 2008/R2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. Set the application up under Windows control (since you mentioned the QMgr is on Windows.)  The app would run as a service, with recovery options to restart it if the service fails.  The application would be programmed (or configured in the case of Q) to process the queue using GETs with a VERY long wait period.  Some additional error handling is required to do something sensible when the QMgr is not available.  This works great for copying messages to multiple queues but isn't appropriate for queue-to-file since the file would never close.
2. Run the application as a WebSphere MQ service.  Defining the `SERVICE` object using `CONTRIL(QMGR)` causes MQ to start the service when the QMgr boots and stop it when the QMgr is shut down.  Since the service is a child process of the QMgr, no need to worry about how to handle errors when the QMgr isn't available.
3. Trigger the program based on non-zero queue depth.  Define a process object describing the command to be executed, enable triggering on the queue with `TRIGTYPE(FIRST)` and run a trigger monitor.  Whenever the queue has depth > 0 and no open input handles, the process object fires and executes the command.  The thing you start must know how to parse the command line so the easiest thing to do if you have someone else's executable is use a script to start it.  The script parses the trigger message and fires off the executable.  Or perhaps the script ignores the trigger message and just runs the exe.  I generally use Korn Shell or Perl and both are available on Windows.

I wrote an article showing how to keep event queues from filling using a triggered version of Q.  The article assumes you want the queues to remain mostly full so uses triggering on depth of about 80%.  The same techniques could be used (in a much simpler implementation, by the way) to fire off the Q program whenever the queue depth became non-zero.

**UPDATE**
Probably should have linked the article.  ;-)
[Mission:Messaging: Easing administration and debugging with circular queues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1103_mismes/1103_mismes.html)